# Accessing file in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a datalog file and need to be saved in database by parsing the data. What are the possible and best ways to access the file if I am hosting it online. I mean it is easy to access the file in a local system but the case is different if hosted online.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it [using SSIS as in this link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic937677-148-1.aspx), or [Transact SQL like in this other](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx).

Hope that helps,